Build fail while compiling

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve project :react-native-video.
Required by:
project :app
> No matching configuration of project :react-native-video was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-vision-camera' with value 'general', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1' but:
- None of the consumable configurations have attributes.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

How to slove these issue

Try the following:

Check react-native-video installation: Ensure that react-native-video is properly installed and linked in your project. Run:
 npm install react-native-video
 npx react-native link react-native-video


Ensure that the react-native-video dependency is correctly added
to your project. In your settings.gradle file, include the
following line:
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')


Verify that the react-native-video module is properly configured in your app/build.gradle file. Add it to the dependencies section:
 implementation project(':react-native-video')


Sometimes, Gradle caches can cause issues. Clean and rebuild your project by running the following commands:
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug



